# How to get columns(Series) back from dropped table?

Tags: python, pandas

```
print(df)

    Names   Maths  Physics  Chemistry
0   Khaja    75       91    84
1   Srihari  81       89    71
2   Krishna  69       77    76
3   jain     87       69    68
4   shakir   79       70    74

df.drop(['Chemistry'],axis=1,inplace=True)

df

    Names   Maths   Physics
0   Khaja     75      91
1   Srihari   81      89
2   Krishna   69      77
3   jain      87      69
4   shakir    79      70
```

> How to get back the dropped column from the table. I tried to get back
>   the column with reset_drop() but it doesn't work.
>
> The final outcome should look like this:

```
 print(df)

        Names   Maths  Physics  Chemistry
    0   Khaja    75       91    84
    1   Srihari  81       89    71
    2   Krishna  69       77    76
    3   jain     87       69    68
    4   shakir   79       70    74
```

Comment: You cannot revert `inplace` change in dataframe.

Comment: If remove column by drop, then column is lost.

Comment: Any other ways than drop to delete the column and can later revert it back to table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column to `Series` and [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to add to end of `DataFrame`:

```
a = df.pop('Chemistry')
print (a)
0    84
1    71
2    76
3    68
4    74
Name: Chemistry, dtype: int64

print (df)
     Names  Maths  Physics
0    Khaja     75       91
1  Srihari     81       89
2  Krishna     69       77
3     jain     87       69
4   shakir     79       70

df = df.join(a)
print (df)
     Names  Maths  Physics  Chemistry
0    Khaja     75       91         84
1  Srihari     81       89         71
2  Krishna     69       77         76
3     jain     87       69         68
4   shakir     79       70         74
```

If column is not last add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by original columns:

```
cols = df.columns
a = df.pop('Maths')
print (a)
0    75
1    81
2    69
3    87
4    79
Name: Maths, dtype: int64

print (df)
     Names  Physics  Chemistry
0    Khaja       91         84
1  Srihari       89         71
2  Krishna       77         76
3     jain       69         68
4   shakir       70         74

df = df.join(a).reindex(columns=cols)
print (df)
     Names  Maths  Physics  Chemistry
0    Khaja     75       91         84
1  Srihari     81       89         71
2  Krishna     69       77         76
3     jain     87       69         68
4   shakir     79       70         74
```

Comment: Thank you @jezrael, can this be applied to large datasets also?

Comment: @jain - Sure, but what is reason for do it? I am a bit curious.

Comment: @jezrael - I hope he has just started with pandas :) ... and exploring ..... good luck to you jain

Comment: I want to know the process what to do,if I mistakenly dropped the column in a larget dataset. Anyway thank you so much.

Comment: @jain - yes, this solution working with one column only... But if use common way with `drop` then removed columns are lost... So `pop` is a bit trick :)

Answer (score 1):

Its always a good practice to have a master Dataframe and then do operations in them
I would suggest keep best naming practice and give subset dataframe meaningful names.

```
print (Master)
     Names  Maths  Physics  Chemistry
0    Khaja     75       91         84
1  Srihari     81       89         71
2  Krishna     69       77         76
3     jain     87       69         68
4   shakir     79       70         74


Chemistry= df.pop('Chemistry')
0    84
1    71
2    76
3    68
4    74
Name: Chemistry, dtype: int64

df_withoutChemistry
     Names  Maths  Physics
0    Khaja     75       91
1  Srihari     81       89
2  Krishna     69       77
3     jain     87       69
4   shakir     79       70
```